# How to sharpen knife with chunk missing?

Tags: knives, sharpening

[image]

Is it better to grind off the whole blade or should I find someone to add metal and then sharpen it again?

Comment: I could be wrong, but my honest thought is to just toss it. If it's a *good* knife, then the composition of metals in the blade may well be different in the body of the knife, so grinding the the current edge off might literally grind off the entire part of the knife meant to keep an edge. For the same reason, I'd think adding metal is a no-go. If it's not a fantastic knife, It's probably worth it just to replace it. Why do you *want* to save it?

Comment: That's a gonner!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grinding the blade down that much would potentially change the shape of the blade. Due to the full depth bolster you would have to either try to reshape the bolster as well or create a blade that tapered very differently. 
The knife is an Oxo Good Grips 8” chefs knife which sells for around £20. It’s difficult to see that either of your options would be as effective as replacing the knife, unless it has sentimental value.

Comment: Yeah, the poor thing's had a rough life; the rest of the blade isn't straight either & it's been sharpened on a rock, so the entire profile already needs re-shaping.. Time to put it out of its misery, I think.

Comment: I'm fairly tolerant of damaged kitchen knives especially as spares, but that would end up in my garden shed (for cutting courgettes off the plant, opening sacks, all sorts of tasks)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same happen to me because I was in a hurry and cut frozen cheese thus being in the same situation as you.

I brought the knife to a professional to have it sharpened and he did a great job of grinding the blade evenly.  That was 5 years ago and the knife is still serving me well.

He asked 15€ to do the job, but that was a fraction of what a new knife would have cost me.  So if you have the tools and knowledge of doing it yourself: **Grind the blade!**  Otherwise, *bring it to a professional; it's not an easy job!*